# Using twitter:// tweetie:// custom scheme on iPhone to open twitter application to a specific user profile

Tags: ios, url, twitter

I thought I was familiar with the applications custom schemes used with iOS to trigger applications from my app but I'm unable to use the ones that seems to be provided by the official twitter app (aka tweetie).

**I'm trying to open the twitter application directly to a predefined user profile.**

From the documentation found here http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/twitter this should be feasible, but this code doesn't work :/ :

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://user?id=41553213"]];`

I also tried with `tweetie://` but the same happens : the application launches, but does not "jump" to the given user profile.
Actually, if I try any of the other examples, I don't get anything working :(

```
twitter://messages
twitter://mentions
```

none of them are working :(

Any idea why none of those invocations are working ?

N.B:I'm using the last version of the twitter application under iOS 3.1.3 (iPhone 3G)

Comment: I just tried a couple of them using Safari and they work. Can you please try with Safari?

Comment: very strange, after removing the application, downloading it again from the appstore, it appears it works ? :O Maybe I wasn't exactly on the very last one ?! At first I thought it was because I had multiple accounts set up, but no, even with that it works now. Strange, but cool.

Comment: I've copy paste my own comment as an answer and marked it as answered.

Comment: How do you get user id on twitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very strange, after removing the application, downloading it again from the appstore, it appears it works ? :O Maybe I wasn't exactly on the very last one ?! At first I thought it was because I had multiple accounts set up, but no, even with that it works now. Strange, but cool.