# How do I open a user's Twitter profile using the Twitter app using a link in iphone Mobile Safari Browser

Tags: iphone, ipad, twitter

How do I open a user's Twitter profile using the Twitter app using a link in Mobile Safari?

Tried code below, did not work.

```
tweetie:///user?screen_name=jessicaalba
twitter:///user?screen_name=jessicaalba
```

Answer (score 1):

You have too many /'s, it should be:

```
twitter://user?screen_name=jessicaalba
```

Also, see these two posts:

[Using twitter:// tweetie:// custom scheme on iPhone to open twitter application to a specific user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449972/using-twitter-tweetie-custom-scheme-on-iphone-to-open-twitter-application)

[How can I open a Twitter tweet using the native Twitter app on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424275/how-can-i-open-a-twitter-tweet-using-the-native-twitter-app-on-ios)

And this page:

http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/twitter

Comment: tried that too did not work, opening in web browser not in twitter app.

Comment: have you done this? are you sure we can do this? In all the reference I see only Native apps can connect to other native apps.

Comment: I have not personally tried it, but it seems that people have confirmed that it works. You should confirm that your iOS, Twitter app, and Safari app are updated to versions that support this scheme.